# Commerce field with no value, but printed

Tags: 7, commerce

My commerce product type has a text field, which is printed even if it has no value.
Every commerce field is printed within a `<div classes_here></div>`. Is there any way to avoid this issue??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link to this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1570058), with a patch for commerce 1.3